# Why does a new activity not start from this OnClick method when not using a button?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I am working in Android Studio and I am using a recycler view to create a list of items from a database. In the OnClick function in the RecyclerViewAdapter, I aim to start a new activity with the extra message from the database (a function that works correctly and is not the problem in this scenario). When the screen is clicked, the app crashes instead of loading the new activity.

Any help to stop the app from crashing would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
//RecyclerViewAdapter
package com.example.penrice9.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Penrice9 on 09/10/2018.
 */

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";
    public static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.penrice9.myapplication.MainActivity";
    private ArrayList<String> eventName = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;
    public LoginScreen ls;
    public Database db;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> eventName, ArrayList<Bitmap> images, Context context) {
            this.eventName = eventName;
        this.images = images;
        this.context = context;
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called.");

        holder.image.setImageBitmap(images.get(position));

        holder.name.setText(eventName.get(position));

        holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, eventName.get(position) + " clicked");
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, eventScreen.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", eventName.get(position));
                context.startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return images.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView name;
        RelativeLayout layout;
        ImageView image;
        CardView card;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            card = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card);
        }
    }


    }


//MainActivity



package com.example.penrice9.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.penrice9.myapplication.eventScreen";
    private ArrayList<String> eventName = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;
    public RecyclerViewAdapter rva;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        getImages();
    }


    public void getImages() {
        images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/90/Stamford_Bridge_Clear_Skies.JPG/1200px-Stamford_Bridge_Clear_Skies.JPG"));
        eventName.add("Chelsea vs Liverpool");

        images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/90/Stamford_Bridge_Clear_Skies.JPG/1200px-Stamford_Bridge_Clear_Skies.JPG"));
        eventName.add("Chelsea vs Cardiff");

        images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2016/11/03/12/west-ham.jpg"));
        eventName.add("West Ham vs Chelsea");

        images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("http://stadiumastro-kentico.s3.amazonaws.com/stadiumastro/media/perform-article/2018/mac/12/toumba-cropped_w0t88ccil23v100heat0tve2z.jpg?ext=.jpg"));
        eventName.add("PAOK vs Chelsea");

        images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("http://www.stadiumguide.com/wp-content/uploads/standrews_front.jpg"));
        eventName.add("Birmingham City vs West Brom ");

        images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fd/Selhurst_Park_Holmesdale_Stand.jpg/1200px-Selhurst_Park_Holmesdale_Stand.jpg"));
        eventName.add("Crystal Palace vs Wolves");

        images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("https://www.thenational.ae/image/policy:1.626869:1504962545/Pawan-Singh-The-National.jpg?f=16x9&w=1200&$p$f$w=4fbc2ca"));
        eventName.add("Pakistan vs Bangladesh");

        images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("http://images.supersport.com/Bloemfontein-Chevrolet-Park-general%20view-120117-G600.jpg"));
        eventName.add("South Africa vs Zimbabwe");

        images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("http://www.kkr.in/img/stadium/eden_garden_new.jpg"));
        eventName.add("India vs West Indies");

        images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("https://www.fanpass.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/O2-Arena-tickets.jpg"));
        eventName.add("Michael McIntyre");

        images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("https://www.fanpass.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/O2-Arena-tickets.jpg"));
        eventName.add("Enrique Iglesias");

        images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("https://www.fanpass.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/O2-Arena-tickets.jpg"));
        eventName.add("Jess Glyne");

        createView();
    }

    public void createView() {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(eventName, images, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }

    public void newPage(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, eventScreen.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}


//Screen to be loaded to, called "eventScreen.java"
package com.example.penrice9.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class eventScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Database db;
    public TextView name, location, date, website;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_screen);
        name = findViewById(R.id.name);
        location = findViewById(R.id.location);
        date = findViewById(R.id.date);
        website = findViewById(R.id.website);


        if (getIntent().hasExtra("name")) {
            String eventName = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
            loadInfo(eventName);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "No message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }




    }

    public void loadInfo(String title){
        String [] info = db.getEventData(title);
        name.setText("the ");
        location.setText("the");
        date.setText("the");
        website.setText("the");
    }
}


//CardView XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/card">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Event"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_gravity="center"            />

    </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


//xml containing recycler view
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.penrice9.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Events"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="50sp"/>


        </RelativeLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>




    --------- beginning of crash
10-18 08:20:37.625 3148-3148/com.example.penrice9.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.example.penrice9.myapplication, PID: 3148
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.penrice9.myapplication/com.example.penrice9.myapplication.eventScreen}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
                                                                                      at com.example.penrice9.myapplication.Database.getEventData(Database.java:92)
                                                                                      at com.example.penrice9.myapplication.eventScreen.loadInfo(eventScreen.java:36)
                                                                                      at com.example.penrice9.myapplication.eventScreen.onCreate(eventScreen.java:24)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace and your ViewHolder XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two most-likely problems are (1) the `eventScreen` activity is not declared in your AndroidManifest.xml or (2) the `context` variable is null.

To solve (1), add this to your manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".eventScreen"/>
```

To solve (2), use the guaranteed-non-null `Context` from your ViewHolder's itemView:

```
Context c = v.getContext();
Log.d(TAG, eventName.get(position) + " clicked");
Intent intent = new Intent(c, eventScreen.class);
intent.putExtra("name", eventName.get(position));
c.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Then you should edit your original post to include the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Your DataBase is null because you did not initialized it.

```
public class eventScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Database db; // db is NULL
    public TextView name, location, date, website;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_screen);
        name = findViewById(R.id.name);
        location = findViewById(R.id.location);
        date = findViewById(R.id.date);
        website = findViewById(R.id.website);

        // You should initialize your DataBase db here before calling loadInfo()

        if (getIntent().hasExtra("name")) {
            String eventName = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
            loadInfo(eventName);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "No message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }




    }

    public void loadInfo(String title){
        // db is still NULL
        // The crash happens here when you call --> db.getEventData() --> null.getEventData(title)
        String [] info = db.getEventData(title);
        name.setText("the ");
        location.setText("the");
        date.setText("the");
        website.setText("the");
    }
}
```